# delete specific db record without an ajax request?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm wondering if there's perhaps a more efficient way to delete a specific db record in MongoDB without using an ajax request? I'm building a travel app using express/mongoose. I have an html form where the user's submission will show up on the page. I'm also using pug to render these pages. Right now I have the following:

Displays user entry:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
  Photo.find({})
    .then((photos) =>{
        res.render('lists', {
        list: photos
    }); 
  })
    .catch((err)=>{
        if (err){
            res.end('error');
        }
    });
});
```

I also have an update details page where users can update their data:

```
router.get('/mylist/:itemid', (req, res, next)=>{
    Photo.findOne({'_id': req.params.itemid})
        .then((photo)=>{
            res.render('update', {
                item: photo
            });     
        }).catch((err)=>{
            if (err){
            console.log(err);
            }
        });

});
```

Ideally, I would like to add an additional button on the update details form page that allows the user to remove their entry. I would really like all of the form behavior just to be contained within my routing file. Anybody have experience with this?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a delete route and a specific ajax request? It would be better practice and probably even less work in the end...

Comment: It's one of the requirements of the project for this class, unfortunately. All the logic has to be handled via server-side code :(